# Find string, highlight found string, scroll to found on iOS device

Tags: ios, find, mobile-safari, highlight, scrollto

I found this script for a Find In Page / Highlight / ScrollTo feature on a page.  On the iPhone, is there a way to style to popup so that it does not have "file://(null)" above the "Find Text"? Also, since I did not create this javascript and since I am not very good with javascript, how would I eliminate the "Found X matches" dialog?

```
<p><strong><a href="javascript:void%28s%3Dprompt%28%27Find%20text%3A%27%2C%27%27%29%29%3Bs%3D%27%28%27+s+%27%29%27%3Bx%3Dnew%20RegExp%28s%2C%27gi%27%29%3Brn%3DMath.floor%28Math.random%28%29*100%29%3Brid%3D%27z%27%20+%20rn%3Bb%20%3D%20document.body.innerHTML%3Bb%3Db.replace%28x%2C%27%3Cspan%20name%3D%27%20+%20rid%20+%20%27%20id%3D%27%20+%20rid%20+%20%27%20style%3D%5C%27color%3A%23000%3Bbackground-color%3Ayellow%3B%20font-weight%3Abold%3B%5C%27%3E%241%3C/span%3E%27%29%3Bvoid%28document.body.innerHTML%3Db%29%3Balert%28%27Found%20%27%20+%20document.getElementsByName%28rid%29.length%20+%20%27%20matches.%27%29%3Bwindow.scrollTo%280%2Cdocument.getElementsByName%28rid%29%5B0%5D.offsetTop%29%3B">Find in this page</a></strong></p>
```

TIA,
Linda

Comment: I should have said that this would be in Mobile Safari.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found that if the "found" string is a link that the script above alters the link so that when I click on it, the linked page does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this with the Wink Toolkit from http://www.winktoolkit.org/